# CardViews with different width and height

Tags: android, kotlin, androidx

Good afternoon people,

I would like to know if I can send my `CardViews` with different width and height?

Equally I leave my xml code since my `CardView` do not have the round corners, does anyone know how to solve it?

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/cardview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:layout_margin="12dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:clipToPadding="true"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="25dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="10dp"
    card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageAceptV"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#FAFAFA"
            android:textAlignment="center" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/details"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#FAFAFA"
            android:textAlignment="center" />

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Likewise in my `CardView` I am displaying it in a `GridView`, I don't know if it has something to do with why the round corners are not visible.

```xml
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".new_fragments.home">

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/my_grid_view_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:columnWidth="150dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="35dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:paddingStart="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:verticalSpacing="22dp" />

</FrameLayout>
```

I leave you a photo of my project how it unfolds

[image]

Comment: Do you by any chance use ```setBackgroundColor(int)``` to change its bg?

Comment: if, for the moment, does it affect something?

Comment: Using ```card.setBackgroundColor( int )``` removes the effect of rounded corners in support libraries (I'm still using them). Use ```card.setCardBackgroundColor ( int )``` instead.

Comment: and to change the width and height of each cardview?

Comment: If I understood correctly, you want to change the width and height dynamically. Then you should use RecyclerView with StaggeredGridLayoutManager, then you can achieve it.